# button colour not changing on hover

Tags: css, button, text, colors, hover

I want the colour of the link in button to be yellow on hover, but it doesn't seem to be working because on hover, the text is still white.

html:

```
<button class="headerbutton headerbutton-style">
     <a href="#">Learn More</a>
</button>
```

css:

```
a, .headerbutton {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in; 
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in; 
}

.headerbutton {
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 12pt;
    border-radius: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 15px 25px;
}

.headerbutton-style {
    background-color: #FAD059;
    border: 2px solid white;
}

.headerbutton-style:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: #FAD05A;
}

.headerbutton a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.headerbutton a:hover {
    color: #FAD05A;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Your code works fine, when I just copy&paste it into a jsfiddle (which would have been your job - please go read [mcve]). Presumably you have more CSS rules that are interfering with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this rule

```
.headerbutton a:hover {
    color: #FAD05A;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

to this

```
.headerbutton:hover a {
    color: #FAD05A;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Then it will work. See this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RaLwEB

Comment: thank you! i knew it was something simple, i appreciate the help.